# IP address doesn't change to the domain name

Tags: web-development, personal-website

I am facing this problem for quite a long time. When I enter the IP address of my website it take me to the website but the IP address doesn't change to the Domain Name. I am hosting my website on a Virtual Machine on Google Cloud. I am using the Google Cloud service as a hosting service for my website. Can someone help me in solving this problem?
This is how my htaccess file now looks like:

## BEGIN WordPress

## The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are

## dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.

## Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^IP\.IP\.IP\.IP [nc,or] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org [nc]
RewriteRule (.*)  http://example.org$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

## END WordPress

Comment: What web server do you have installed and running? What configuration are you using for its virtual hosts?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the requested details so that this could be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Since multiple hostnames can resolve to the same IP address, this is something that has to be handled at the HTTP level.

You should issue a `301 Moved Permanently` status and a `Location` header with the same path but replacing the IP address with the desired hostname.

You might be able to configure your HTTP server to do that. You might have to do it with explicit server-side programming.

e.g. in PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != "localhost") {
    http_response_code(301);
    header("Location: https://localhost/" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    exit();
}
```

or with Apache HTTP mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://localhost%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I think I have already made these changes to my htaccess file. Can you please see it in the question and tell me if its right because it's not working.